# Python self-referential list produces weird output on sorted

Tags: python, list

I recently came across a weird discrepancy when trying to sort self-referential lists using `.sort()` and `sorted()`. I was hoping someone could shed some light on this. The code in question is the following:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3]

lst[0] = lst
lst[1] = lst
lst[2] = lst

print(lst)

print(sorted(lst))

lst.sort()

print(lst)
```

The above code produces the following output:

```sh
[[...], [...], [...]]
[[[...], [...], [...]], [[...], [...], [...]], [[...], [...], [...]]]
[[...], [...], [...]]
```

It's the output from `print(sorted(lst))` that baffles me. Wonder if it is some form of recursion that's causing it?

Comment: `sort` and `sorted` don't really have anything to do with that. It's enough to compare the output of `print(l)` and `print(list(l))`

Comment: In other words, it is due to how new lists are constructed from an existing, self-reffering list, not to sorting

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I'm going to call your list `x`, because frankly `l` looks too much like the number one and is throwing me off. So you've got a list `x` which looks like this

```
[x, x, x]
```

Now, we do

```
print(x)
```

Python is smart enough to say "hey, look, this list contains itself recursively, let's not print it again inside of itself." All of the places `x` appears in your list, we get `[...]`

```
[[...], [...], [...]]
```

Now consider

```
x.sort()
print(x)
```

We sort the list, which doesn't do much since every element is the same. However, crucially, it all happens *in-place*. The list started out looking like `[x, x, x]` and will end looking like `[x, x, x]`, where `x` is our list. So the print looks the same.

```
[[...], [...], [...]]
```

Finally, your fun example.

```
sorted(x)
```

`sorted`, unlike `list.sort`, does *not* modify the list and instead produces a *new* list. Let's call this new list `y`. In your `x.sort` example, at the end,  we have the *same* list `x` that looks like `x = [x, x, x]`. When we print the list, we *immediately* see the recursion and stop printing.

However, `sorted(x)` produces a *new* list. The list will still look like `[x, x, x]`, but it's *not* the list `x`. It's a new list `y = [x, x, x]`.

Now, we do

```
print(sorted(x))
```

Python sees a list of three elements: `[x, x, x]`. We look at each of those elements. We're printing `y`, so the fact that this list contains `x` is *not* a recursion problem; it's a perfectly ordinary list that contains other lists. So we print `x` inside of `y`. Now, one more layer down, we look inside `x` and see that it contains, lo and behold, `x` again. That *is* a recursion problem, but it happened one step later, because we made a new list that, although it looks identical to the original, is distinct.

```
[[[...], [...], [...]], [[...], [...], [...]], [[...], [...], [...]]]
```

Comment: I prefer `L` instead of `l` or `x`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: names starting with an uppercase letter are typically used for constants.

Comment: Constants or classes; in any case not variables, for which the convention is `snake_case`. I personally see many data scientists and university students especially go against this and it makes their code so much harder to read.

Comment: @EricDuminil I always emphasis on readability over practice and rules. I do not use `L` in project code but for this use-case `L` looks better than `x`  *to me*  -- still  it is inexact science and everyone has their own preference. Yes, capitals mostly apt for constant naming.

Comment: @theberzi: It's possible to write FORTRAN in any language. :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you thought after `lst[0] = lst` that `lst` would be `[[1,2,3],2,3]`. If so, you'd be assuming  `= lst` [passes by value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value). But lists are [passed by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference), so at that point `lst` is `[lst,2,3]`.

To pass by value, use `lst[0] = list(lst)` etc. This time the right-hand side creates a new list, with the same value as before but a new reference, since in this context `list(lst)` is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `[v for v in lst]`.

As @DeepSpace noted, this fact about `list` also explains why `print(list(lst))` is three times more verbose than `print(lst)`; it prints `[v for v in lst]`, which is just `[lst, lst, lst]`.

Comment: We don't have these two *"call/pass by value"* *"call/pass by reference"* terminologies in Python.